# Iframe print issue in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, iframe

I am using below piece of code to print an iframe with large data but in firefox it is only printing first page, the firefox don't print rest pages.

```
     window.frames[frameID].focus();
     window.frames[frameID].print();
```

Please suggest if any change is needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: It is not a duplicate. I have this same issue and its not related to origin policy at all.

Comment: I have resolved the issue it was a small css change

Answer (score 0):

I was found ability to print in Firefox with next statement:

```
 frame.focus();
 frame.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = '';
 frame.contentDocument.write(content);
 frame.contentWindow.print();
```

Works with Firefox 54.

Hope this helps anybody.